# Optimal way to read a book having N chapters in M days

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across this interview question: Given a book with N chapters (each chapter has of course different number of pages), what is the optimal way to complete the entire book in M days with the constraint that a chapter has to be read completely on the same day.

Example:

```
Chapters[] = {7, 5, 3, 9, 10}
Days = 4
```

One should read:

`Chapter1 on Day1`, `Chapters2 and Chapter3 on Day2`, 
`Chapter4 on Day3` and `Chapter5 on Day4`.

I understand that the idea should be to minimize the sum of absolute differences of total pages read with the average number of pages that one should 'ideally' read on one day. However, I am not able to translate this idea to a data structure and an algorithm. Any other idea or inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to read the chapters consecutively? Meaning, after chapter 1 you should read chapter 2, not 5 or 7.

Comment: @m3th0dman question is important, if it should be consecutively, it means we have one more constraint too.

Comment: Yes, chapters have to be read strictly consecutively, and all the chapters have to be read at the end of day M.

Comment: Did the question state that the optimal way should minimize the sum of absolute differences?

Comment: No it doesn't. But I guess that's implicit. You don't want to read multiple chapters on one day which would make the total number of pages read on that day too many and for other days, too less. Remember, it says 'optimal' way of reading the book. Hence, I thought we can start off with this idea.

Comment: Clearly, the optimal solution is to read N chapters in 1 day such that you have M-1 days left to spend on watching the Star Trek: TNG rerun.

Comment: @user1639485 We cannot "assume" or guess what the question considers as an optimal solution. You will have to specify the objective function in a precise manner.

Comment: This might be an interesting problem, but the exposition is terrible. OP you should rewrite the question to make clear the objective and constraints. Well done for giving an example case and solution but you need to explain _how_ —why— the solution is correct.

Comment: How many pages can one read in one day? This is what is missing here. My guess is that the example has that number at 10. Also that is implied from the example is that chapters are read in sequence as well, i.e. must not read Chapter 1 and 3 (7+3=10).

Comment: by "optimal" do you mean the most evenly distributed number of pages a day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming.

1. The average is equal to `totalNumberOfPages / numberOfDays` and it does not depend on the way we read the book.
2. The state is (number of chapters we have finished, the number of days we have already spent). The value of a state is the minimum sum of absolute differences so far.
3. The base case if `f(0, 0) = 0`.
4. Transitions are as follows:

   - Let's assume that the current state is `(chapters, days)`.
   - We can iterate over the number of chapters we will read the next day(I will call it `add`) and make the following transition: `f(chapters + add, days + 1) = min(f(chapters + add, days + 1), f(chapters, days) + abs(average - the number of pages in chapter + 1 ... chapter + add chapters).`
5. The answer is `f(totalNumberOfChapters, totalNumberOfDays)`.

This solution is based on an assumption that our goal is to "minimize the sum of absolute differences of total pages read with the average number of pages that one should 'ideally' read on one day".

But if the problem statement does not say what the criterion of optimality is, I would suggest minimizing the maximum number of pages read during one day(in my opinion, the goal not too read to much in a row makes more sense). In this case, there is a more simple and efficient solution:
we can binary search over the answer and use a greedy algorithm to check if a fixed candidate is feasible.

Comment: Minimizing the maximum number of pages read during one day seems a better a criterion. Could you elaborate more on your solution for this criterion?

Comment: The solution proposed seems to return some number. The objective is to return a list of list of chapters (telling which chapter(s) to read on Day1 till DayM). I can't figure where that's happening. Further, how do you define your function f(i,j) for j>i (Number of Days are more than number of chapters: should it be i).

Comment: @user1639485 It is possible to reconstruct the answer itself(as a list of chapters per day) using standard dynamic programming solution reconstruction techniques. `j > i` is fine(we can read nothing during some days).