# Algorithm to find the best possible sum in C

Tags: c, algorithm, linear-programming

We have given a list of N numbers.

We then create 3 partitions A, B and C (thse can be just integers). We want to store the numbers in the three partitions in such way that the partition with the biggest sum to have the least minimum difference from the second and the third sum. So we want to store the numbers in that way so the sum of all partitions to be as close as possible between each other. The way we should store the numbers is linear. By that I mean every sum should have numbers that are one-next-to-the-other sequence. I don't know if you understand me so if someone has, please edit my question properly.

I will provide an example bellow to show you how.

Let's say we have the following numbers : *8 5 4 3 2 1 3*

The best solution is :

```
A = 8
B = 5 + 4 = 9
C = 3 + 2 + 1 + 3 = 9
```

I wanted to create a linear complexity solution of the problem but I don't know how. I created a O(n^2) solution but I wanted to sure if there is better solution. maybe logarythmic. I will not  upload my code just not to confuse you guys. If you want then I will.

The solution I want can be provided in C or just in an algorithm!

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I saw the link and no solution is provided for my problem. It's not dublicate so please remove the lable.

Comment: It's exactly the same but it talks about chapters and days. With your example you read the first 8 chapters on day 1, the next 9 in the second day and the next 9 in day 3.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor no. Cause first the algorythm isn't provided. Second I want the to keep the biggest number. Third I want the fifferences between the numbers to be as closer as possible to each others. Fourth I said that the three partitions take the numbers in spesific sequence and every partition should have at least one number. And of course the answer isn't very well provided.

Comment: Only the algorithm description is missing because no one posted an algorithm yet. The third and fourth is exactly the same as the duplicate. The maximum number is trivial when you find a solution.

Comment: [kraskevich's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28557877/2144669) is all that can be expected in the absence of a bounty. Requesting a C implementation is plzsendtehcodez. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yes but I can't undesrand the logic! How do I make the algorythm? Just a hint guys!

Comment: @Bill Consider posting a question that refers to the linked duplicate and explains precisely what is it that you don't understand. Crying "I can't understand" over the whole thing is not constructive and won't take you anywhere.